# Почему ajax возвращает только один объект?

Tags: c#, ajax

Не могу понять, почему на клиент возвращается только один объект, хотя на сервере проверял, в переменной q все данные лежат.

C#:

```
    public JsonResult Data(int? id)
    {            
        var collection = DBConnection.GetInstance().GetCollection<DBData>("DBData");
        List<DBData> data = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList().Take(20).ToList();

        var q = Json(data);

        return Json(data);
    }
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
showLoader();

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Data/" + 0,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    complete: function () {
        hideLoader();
    }
});
};
```

В data хранятся объекты типа DBData, а DBData представляет собой:

```
public class DBData
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string CVE { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public BsonDateTime PublishedDT { get; set; }
    public BsonDateTime ModifiedDT { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public string AccessComplexity { get; set; }
    public string VulnerabilityDB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Что лежит в переменной `q` и что Вы получаете в `data` в `JS`?

Comment: @DenisBubnov в data на JS только первый объект и то не все поля в нём. А в q.Value лежит полный список моих объектов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать следующим образом:

В C#:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
return Json(json);
```

В JS в `success`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var list = data;
    $.each(list, function (index, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

Если после этого в методе падает исключение, то это ошибка во время сериализации, может для типа `ObjectId` или `BsonDateTime`. Попробуйте вернуть сначала простые типы данных в массиве, такие как `string`, а потом уже более сложные. Возможно имеет смысл поменять `BsonDateTime` на `DateTime`.

Comment: Я использую C# Core и в нём нет JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Comment: @V.Bylbas...не заметил этого у Вас в вопросе. А если `JS` написать, как я предложил?

Comment: Извините, что не указал за C# Core. А в JS изменил на Ваш код, но всё равно только один объект

Comment: @V.Bylbas, тогда упакуйте данные через `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: @V.Bylbas, посмотрите в ответе добавил сериализацию данных `JSON`

Comment: Начал возвращать ошибку: GET http://localhost:33651/Home/Data/0 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @V.Bylbas, я так понимаю, что в методе падает исключение. Используйте *Firefox/Firebug*, чтобы посмотреть фактический ответ, который Вы получаете от сервера. Я так подозреваю, что ошибка во время сериализации, может для типа `ObjectId` или `BsonDateTime`. Попробуйте вернуть сначала простые типы данных в массиве, такие как `string`, а потом уже более сложные.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам за помощь, BsonDateTime изменил на DateTime всё сразу заработало